# How to pass arguments to system call at xv6?

Tags: c, operating-system, xv6

I am trying to implement a new system call at xv6.
Had some trouble to pass arguments.
Lets say this is my system call.

```
sys_mySystemcall(int* x ,struct myStruct * y);
```

How do I get these 2 pointers at sysproc.c?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The helper functions argint, argptr, argstr,and argfd retrieve the n’th system call argument, as either an integer, pointer, a string,or a file descriptor.